# Unexplained reset of my form with casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to fill and submit the "Rechercher un billet pas cher" form of this website : [Kelbillet](http://www.kelbillet.com/)

I manage to fill the form but right after clicking on 'Rechercher' the website reset it.

I can't post the pictures.

Here is my code :

```
var liens = [];
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.start('http://www.kelbillet.com/', function() {
  this.fill('form#form-search', {'depart': 'Paris', 'arrivee': 'Marseille', 'date_aller': '19/05/15'}, false);
  this.capture("result1.png");
  this.click('input[value="Rechercher"]');
  this.capture("result2.png");
  this.waitForUrl(/recherche/, function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
  });
});

casper.run(function(){
  this.exit();
});
```

If I do it manually it works. Why is my form reset ?

Comment: According to the documentation for [fill](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill) in casper, it takes 'true' to actually submit the form.

Comment: I didn't use 'true' because its behaviour is erratic, it doesn't work on some forms. I have the same issue using true instead of the click method.

Comment: It behaves that way because most forms have extra logic and behaviour attached to them in javascript. Auto submitting a form works almost only when it's a pure html form.

Comment: In this case it doesn't seem to be a submitting issue, because casperjs find the button to click on.

Comment: most inputs have event handlers defined for validation and often things like dropdowns are custom implementations build in javascript/ jquery. So in orde to be able to submit the form through casperjs you would have to debug/ investigate what and how needs to be triggered from javascript.